# Test case library for java.util.List implementations

Tags: java, unit-testing, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a testsuite for Java custom collections implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068503/is-there-a-testsuite-for-java-custom-collections-implementation)

Is there a test case library available that I can use to ensure a custom implementation of `java.util.List` is done correctly?

I can certainly write my one test cases, but given the nature of all of the `List` methods, it seems tricky to ensure that the tests are comprehensive.

Similarly, it'd be great to have test cases for the entire set of Java collections interfaces.

Comment: I think it will be a good idea for someone (Sun, the guys at Junit, me :D ...) to write public test cases from this kind of writespread classes.

Comment: Whoops, looks like you may be right.

Comment: I just found it after trying to find better documentation for `guava-testlib` ;-) Looks like there's a no good, official documentation for that.

Comment: I'll give it a go. I'm guessing it will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Guava folks](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) have written a collection testing library called `guava-testlib` because ... they are implementing lots of collections.

The best documentation I found at the moment is [this third-party blog post](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2012/09/google-guava-collection-test-suite/), however. It is briefly mentioned in [their ContributorSetUp Wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ContributorSetUp).

Comment: Go figure that Google has stepped up to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at implemenations of [`org.apache.commons.collections.list.AbstractTestList`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/testapidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/AbstractTestList.html#testListAddByIndex%28%29). May be this is what you want.